# Process excel formula in VBA without pasting it in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm iterating through a table of user data.

The macro then does something with the data of each user, but I want to add a way to only select certain users with a formula that is entered through a UserForm

Is there any way to have a formula like `=AND($K2>30000;$C2<>"W")` processed for every single cell I'm iterating through (with relative cell references)?

Comment: I don't really want to do that, because that would make the handling for the people who are going to use the document way harder (And I want to minimize the risk of someone not being able to use the makro). If it was for myself this would have been a good way of solving the issue though.

Comment: can you add the code that you are using and will ultimately set the formula? This may help us provide a creative solution for you.

Comment: I'm sorry that's not possible since I'm not allowed to make parts of the code public :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll be easier to maintain with relative references, so give this a try :

```
Dim c as Range
For Each c in Selection.Cells
    c.formula = "=AND($K" & c.Row & ">30000,$C" & c.Row & "<>" & Chr(34) & "W" & Chr(34) & ")"
Next c
```

Comment: I don't think I can use that because since I don't know the formula before it's being entered and therefore can't just replace the referenced row number with `c.Row`. Also, wouldn't your method post the formula somewhere? If yes, is that absolutely required and is there no way to just do `result = processFormula(formula)`?

Comment: The formula should be inputed into the processed cell `c` with my code, but if you only want the result it's possible too. But as you don't know which formula will be entered, all of this will be very tricky...** Why not propose a few tests/conditions** (like `>` here) that the user can set limits (like `30000` here) and the column (`K` here)? With that you will be able to create some code to do the calculations directly!

Comment: I'm probably going to do that if I don't find an easy way of processing a formula.. I just would have prefered it because I thought it would have been simpler than just writing my own parser for the userinput.

Comment: yup, I had to do that in a project (a long time ago), but I add only two variables to identify in the formula that was inputed from the userform, and I had to struggle quite a long time to make it work, so I think a few test would work more easily in your case which seems wider!